# Remove scroll from android:list

Tags: android, android-listview

is there a possibility to remove scroll from android:list
because i m using it in a fragment and i have scroll on my main activity so i want all list items to be shown without scroll

```
<ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
             />
```

Comment: Which view do you need? Why do you want use List View?

Comment: i need to use list for showing list of items using custom adapter and when i use @+id/ it doesnt work... any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//listView is your ListView
listView.setScrollContainer(false);
```

or this

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
   if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
      return true;
   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate specifically you want to disable listview scrolling arribute or just remove scroll bars...

Scrollbars can be removed by following code in list view:-

android:scrollbars="none"

Comment: i wanted to disable the scrolling attribute and i have fixed it myself thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this my using @+id/mylist

i have changed ListFragment to Fragment and using this list in layout

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/mylist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
             />
```

Answer (score 0):

no way to do that, the scrollview always scroll, you should create custom view for your issue